# printf() and _write() in newlib-nano

Tags: embedded, printf, newlib

I use newlib-nano in an embedded project.
I have implemented my version of `_write()` to make `printf()` output chars to UART.

I wonder if a single call of `printf()` results in a single call of `_write()`, or, otherwise `_write()` can be called more than once by `printf()`.

best regards
Max

Comment: Why you don't trace yourself `len` parameter...code is yours....

Comment: because I need to be sure to output on the uart the whole formatted output of a printf. Since I am in a multithread context (I use FreeRTOS) It could happend that a single printf could be splitted and another printf (from another task) could outputs its character between the two slices of splitted string.My doubt is that `_write()` is called with the whole formatted string as parameters. I wonder if (under certain circumstances) the string could be splitted, so I have more than one call to `_write()` (at least a call every caracter)

Comment: You need to look yourself, unfortunately.  From experience, however, every `printf()` implementation I've used or implemented is not thread safe and/or does not prevent interleaving of output from different invocations.  `_write()` could also called multiple times from within `printf()` as a means to reduce memory (no need for intermediate buffers)